# Is there a way to back to line dynamically when there is not enough space while using material ui datagrid componenet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using datagrid component from material ui, I bring some data from a database and try to pass it to the datagrid component.
Some fields contain long strings and not all of them appear in the column (Titre PFE) .
[image]

What I'm trying to do is to display something like that :

Développement d’une application mobile
ecommerce

```js
     <div style={{ height: 515, width: "100%" }}>
            <DataGrid
              rows={pfeList}
              columns={columns}
              pageSize={8}
              autoPageSize
              rowsPerPageOptions={[7]}
            />
          </div>
```

```js
  const columns = [
    {
      field: "titre",
      headerName: "Titre PFE",
      headerAlign: "center",
      width: 380,
    },
.
.
.
.
.
];
```

What should I fix here to get the desired result?

Comment: You can add `sx={{ whiteSpace: 'normal' }}` to your datagrid

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that properly, you need to make the heights of the rows [dynamic](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-height/#dynamic-row-height). You can add `getRowHeight={() => "auto"}` prop to DataGrid to make rows dynamic.

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-night-0jc14i?file=/demo.tsx:1813-1840) for a live working example of this solution.